# manage and compile large emberjs app

Tags: ember.js

Ember don't seems to play well with requirejs or building with r.js without some hackery.

Bit hard to manage a large application, I like to break down my file structure as HMVC, which manages modules bit easier :

```
app
  - blah
  - modules
      -module1
       - controller
       - model 
       - view.
```

Has anyone come up a build stack to automate the compilation into single file with dependency management?

Comment: Sounds Ok, but not enough info. I had success with Extjs. Mixim libraries is a problem unless you learn to do proper namespacing in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: You should now be starting new projects using [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli), which provides all the build/dev tools plus many other useful features.

---

**Original answer:**

An example Ember project using [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) as a build system:

https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

I've used this as a starting point for some Ember apps and it works well.

Comment: grunt-neuter is exactly what i'm looking for, and a bonus of grunt-ember-template. nice stuff!! I almost restart the project in simrou + require + jquery + loadash + dotJs... because i couldnt do the concatenation for ember.... awesome neuter.

Comment: unfortunately the link is dead

Comment: You said "You should now be starting new projects using ember-cli", but in github project page there is a big warning: "Although potentially exciting, this is still really a WIP". Given that, I'm not sure that using ember-cli for real-word important projects is safe nowadays...

Comment: ember-cli is under heavy development and it will be part of the official Ember docs/guides/suggested build system. Specifically the recently published (2014-11-03) [post about the road to 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) specifically mentions "You should begin moving your app to Ember CLI as soon as possible."

Answer (score 1):

> Ember don't seems to play well with requirejs or building with r.js without some hackery.

Why do you want to use `require.js` in the first place?

As for making this all work you'll need a build tool. I recommend [brunch](http://brunch.io) (Node) or [iridium](https://github.com/radiumsoftware/iridium) (Ruby). Brunch is more simple and supports many different module formats. Iridium is much more powerful. It uses Minispade for modules. Require.js/AMD is not needed because your js is always delivered as a single concatenated file.

Comment: nice, havent browse brunch for a while, thought they only have the backbone skeleton. but i would still choose grunt, part of my daily using stack.

Answer (score 0):

For stand-alone ember dev I use ember-skeleton as a starting point, which is itself based primarily on rake-pipeline.

https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton

This provides the whole kit-and-kaboodle for beginning an app, but the meat of it is the rake-p Assetfile, which describes how rake-pipeline will digest all the files, filter their contents, and ultimately combine them into the final handful of files. Additionally, the combination of loader.js and the minispade filter allows the use of 'require()' statements for managing dependencies amongst your files.

Comment: any none rails related methods? more looking towards pure js, node pipelines.

Comment: Well, ruby, not rails, but yeah this option does use gems, rack, rake, etc.